# Tag 'amp-story' is not allowed to have any sibling tags ('body' should only have 1 child).UNKNOWN line 1038, column 0

Tags: templates, blogger, amp-story

I am trying to implement amp-story in blogspot template. While trying to validate in AMP Validator; it is showing the only error

**"Tag 'amp-story' is not allowed to have any sibling tags ('body' should only have 1 child)."**

In the window of "the AMP VALIDATOR", on deletion the code "b:section id='fixelements' showaddelement='no', which was the only code in the "body" section [other than amp-story codes]  it is showing

**Validation Status: PASS**

But after deletion from my blogspot theme template, it is showing error :

**"We did not find any section in your theme. A theme must have at least one b:section tag."**

Please help.

Comment: Please post either the URL to the page having this problem, or the full source code of the page.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on this URL: https://studysciences.com/stories/tips-to-keep-your-surroundings-clean-during-covid-19-pandemic/
What should I do?